# How does ActiveRecord enforce has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How does ActiveRecord enforce the has_one relationship? (versus has_many relationship)

It seems that it does NOT and I have to create a unique constraint using migration
(that is, on the MySQL table level).

I think ActiveRecord should handle this constraint and not rely on the database\
table-level enforcement.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 7):

I think it doesn't force the unique constraint. It works almost exactly like `has_many` does, except that when the database query is executed to retrieve the related object, a `LIMIT 1` clause is added to the generated SQL.